# How many email addresses can be in a SOA DNS record?

Tags: email, dns, soa, nameservers

For example, I want to add two or more email addresses to SOA - hostmaster.domain.com and johndoe.gmail.com

If it is possible, how should it look like?

Also, can such email addresses in SOA like *hostmaster@domain.com*, or *hostmaster.domain.com.johndoe.gmail.com* break the DNS zone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible, you can have only one email address encoded in a SOA record.

As for the second part, I do not know what you mean by "break the zone".
You need to have a valid SOA record, which means among other things changing the `@` for a `.` to encode the email address.